# How to download images automatically from database table when it is updated?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, .net, azure-blob-storage

I have this sample code to download images from database table manually by clicking a button.

In Html page:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Convert Byte to All Image " OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ToString();
            SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(sConn);
            objConn.Open();
            string sTSQL = "Select TOP 1500 FileData, FileValue from Demo_Tbl where Active=1 and FileGroup='C_Photo'";
            SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand(sTSQL, objConn);
            objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.SelectCommand = objCmd;
            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 10000;
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            objConn.Close();
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string FileValue = dt.Rows[i]["FileValue"].ToString();
                object FileData = dt.Rows[i]["FileData"];
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("/Images/" + FileValue), (byte[])FileData);
            }
            Response.Write("Images has been fetched");
        }
```

I want this download to happen automatically when **Demo_Tbl** table is updated by some one each time. Also I want the download target folder in cloud database(https.clode.azure.com) blobs.

I need some one to help me on this since I'm clue less.

Comment: Updating means you are triggering a specific method to update a row. Then you could make the download in the specific folder with the method I guess.

Comment: @AT-2016 - I'm not much familiar with triggers. Yes, this table will be updated by some random person and at this time I want my code to run and download images automatically.

Comment: When you update the table that means you update a row and you do this using a method. Why don't you do this automatic download on the update event?

Comment: @AT-2016 - Yeah, its a good idea to download on the update event. Let me try on it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Yeah, its a good idea to download on the update event.

If you write the download code on the update event, it will need to wait the download method before the update event finished. I would recommend you to insert a queue message to Azure storage queue, then use Azure webjob QueueTrigger to download the file to Azure Blob. [Here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-get-started/) is a similar scenario that use Azure Webjob QueueTrigger to resize the image. I think it will help with your scenario.

Comment: _ Thanks let me look on it